# Right justify string inserted in EditText Android, does not show as expected

Tags: android, insert, formatting, android-edittext

I have a custom Edit Text(Lined Edit Text) which I want to show separate line for each value that I inserted as a formatted
string with a width of 20.
I already checked the formatted string length. Is always the same despite the number length. I
guess the problem is somewhere in the insert method.

```
I tried different values for android:gravity and android:textAlingment but I still 
get the same result.

Then I thought is from the customized EditText and have tried same thing for an EditText and get same 
behavior.

  Any ideas how I can fix this ????


  I expected to get a result like this :

   +         45323    
   +             3
   +            20
   +          4563 

   But instead I get :

   +          1
   +         222
   +        33333

   sort of a triangle.
```

```
     int startIndex = verticalCalculator.getLayout().getLineStart(getCurrentCursorLine());
     int endIndex = verticalCalculator.getLayout().getLineEnd(getCurrentCursorLine());
     String text = verticalCalculator.getText().subSequence(startIndex,endIndex).toString();

     String lineToInsert = String.format(Locale.US,"+%20.2f",valueFromText);  
     verticalCalculator.getText().delete(startIndex,endIndex);
     verticalCalculator.getText().insert(startIndex,lineToInsert);
     verticalCalculator.getText().insert(verticalCalculator.getSelectionEnd(),"\n+"); 
     verticalCalculator.requestFocus();
```

```
  <com.example.firstapp.LinedEditText
            android:id="@+id/verticalCalculator"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />
```

[it looks like a triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVyWL.jpg)

[with gravity = "right" only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8tu9.jpg)

Comment: What is LinedEditText? Is that your widget?

Comment: It extends edittext and i customized it so it looks like a notebook page with horinzontal lines

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:gravity="right"`

and remove `android:textAlignment="..."`

Comment: I just did that...like this the text just starts always from the right side and i my intention is to write left to right

Comment: Sorry, I don't exactly understand. Can you post a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: I put a link in my initial post.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what it looks like with my suggested changes

Comment: should look like this but left side aligned

Comment: You can't do it this way. the width of a space is different from the width of a digit. Your code assumes that both spaces and digits take up the same amount of width.

Comment: First i thought that  String.format(%20s) gives the word the space to the right that it needs to expand regardless of it s length in order to keep the right side limit.

Comment: Please try using `"+%020.2f"` as your format string and see if that makes any difference in the alignment. This will replace the leading spaces with leading zeroes in the output. Make another screenshotn with the results

Comment: I think I fixed it by adding to xml EditText attr android:typeface="monospace". I am testing it now